# Why does acquiring an Azure AD token by refresh token have no signing algorithm?

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, adal4j

When I get a token by authorization code (`authContext.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode`), I get a JWT (idToken) that is signed and has the proper headers:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "wLLmYfsqdQuWtV_-hnVtDJJZM3Q",
  "kid": "wLLmYfsqdQuWtV_-hnVtDJJZM3Q"
}
```

but when I use the refresh token to get a new token (`authContext.acquireTokenByRefreshToken(...)`), it returns an unsigned JWT:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "none"
}
```

How do I get it to give me a signed JWT?

`return authContext.acquireTokenByRefreshToken(
    refreshToken,
    new ClientCredentials(
        clientId,
        clientSecret
    ),
    null
);`

Comment: You are getting idToken back from first call i.e. `authContext.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` but the second call i.e. `authContext.acquireTokenByRefreshToken` will return you Access Token, Refresh token and information on access token's expiration time as per documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.aad.adal4j._authentication_context.acquiretokenbyrefreshtoken?view=azure-java-stable   Can you please share more details on which part of returned information are you looking at? and which resource exactly are you acquiring this token for etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not reproduce your issue on my side. I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) to get `Authentication code` and acquire `access token` and `refresh token` with below code successfully. Please refer to it.

```
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class GetTokenByAuthenticationCode {

    private static final String APP_ID = "***";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "***";
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8080";
    private static final String tenant = "***";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant + "/oauth2/authorize";
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        String code = "***";

        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true, service);

        URI url = new URI(REDIRECT_URI);

        Future<AuthenticationResult> result = context.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                code,
                url,
                new ClientCredential(APP_ID, APP_SECRET),
                null
        );
        String token = result.get().getAccessToken();
        System.out.println(token);
        String refreshToken = result.get().getRefreshToken();
        System.out.println(refreshToken);


        Future<AuthenticationResult> result1 = context.acquireTokenByRefreshToken(
                refreshToken,
                new ClientCredential(APP_ID, APP_SECRET),
                null
        );

        String tokenNew = result1.get().getAccessToken();
        String refreshTokenNew = result1.get().getRefreshToken();
        System.out.println(tokenNew);
        System.out.println(refreshTokenNew);
    }
}
```

Decode:

[image]

---

Update Answer:

Firstly, sorry for the mistake. I replaced `getIdToken` with `getAccessToken`, the result is as same as you.Then I searched the response parameters in [Authorize access to Azure Active Directory web applications using the OAuth 2.0 code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-authorization-code-to-request-an-access-token), you could find the statement of `id_token` parameter.

> An unsigned JSON Web Token (JWT) representing an ID token. The app can
>   base64Url decode the segments of this token to request information
>   about the user who signed in. The app can cache the values and display
>   them, but it should not rely on them for any authorization or security
>   boundaries.

So, the id token just a segment which can't be relied on. If you want to get the complete id token, please refer to the [openId flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code).

Comment: you're getting the access token. the id token is unsigned

Comment: @DonRhummy Sorry for the mistake. Would you please post your sample code for getting the id token? So that I could test on my side.