# Microsoft Graph and Java - Multiple calls against authorization code flow

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've been trying to figure this one out for a few hours, and I'm now going in circles and wasting fun RnD time.  I'm playing with the MS Graph API to access Office 365, and I've got it set up using the Authorization flow to authorise my Java servlet.  It works fine (the URL to get the auth code is elsewhere) but I can only run one call. I get the following error in the exceptions for subsequent calls (in my code, it is when I try to look at the Drive):

**OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.**

I'm assuming that this means I need to refresh my token (obvious really, and I've found notes about this saying that it is now necessary on this flow), but I can't figure out how to do it using the GraphServiceClient.

My code is below, any help would be most welcome at this point before I frisbee my laptop out of the nearest window.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String code = request.getParameter("code");

        String clientId = "***";
        String clientSecret = "***";
        String authorisationCode = code; 
        String redirectURL = "http://localhost:8080/O365Web/auth";
        String tenant = "***";

        AuthorizationCodeCredential authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret) //required for web apps, do not set for native apps
                .authorizationCode(authorisationCode)
                .redirectUrl(redirectURL)               
                .build();

        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
        scopes.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
        scopes.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.All");
        scopes.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access");

        TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, authCodeCredential);      

        GraphServiceClient graphClient =
                GraphServiceClient
                .builder()              
                .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)                
                .buildClient();

        try {
            final User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
            out.println("Name: " + me.displayName + "");
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            out.println("Exception in first user get: " + ex.getMessage() );    
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            DriveItemCollectionPage children = graphClient.me().drive().root().children().buildRequest().get();

            while ( children != null ) {

                for ( DriveItem item : children.getCurrentPage() ) {
                    out.println("C:" + item.name + " : " + item.id);
                }

                DriveItemCollectionRequestBuilder builder = children.getNextPage();
                if ( builder != null ) {
                    out.println("Loading page...");
                    children = children.getNextPage().buildRequest().get();
                } else {
                    children = null;
                }
            }
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            out.println("Exception in children get: " + ex.getMessage());   
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            final User me2 = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
            out.println(me2.displayName + "<br/>");
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            out.println("Exception in second user get: " + ex.getMessage());    
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

When I ran the request first, I was able to generate the access token

When I ran the same request again, I also got the same error:

**OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token**

The reason for the error is the authorization code used in the authCodeCredential can be used only once

```
String authorisationCode = code;
```

If you want to make new request, you can generate the new authorization code (the URL to get the auth code is elsewhere) and use it in the authCodeCredential

This could solve the issue

Another way is to use Refresh Token.

While generating the authorization code using URL, you can add another scope with **offline_access**

Now, while generating the access token with the authorization code, add another scope with **offline_access**.
This will generate a refresh token along with access token.

Now, you can use the refresh token to generate a new access token when the access token expires

Reference: [Get access on behalf of a user - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought - however I can't figure out how to do it from inside the Java classes - I can't even spot how to get the refresh token out of the TokenCredentialAuthProvider or the GraphServiceClient.

And going back for a fresh authorization token each time isn't going to be an option, I need to process multiple actions.

Comment: Check if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730314/why-does-acquiring-an-azure-ad-token-by-refresh-token-have-no-signing-algorithm